# Chrome Extension - Can background.js access a local html page when it's not the active tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When the user clicks on a button in popup.html of my chrome extension, it opens form.html which has a textarea where the user can input text. After the user inputs text into the textarea, I want background.js to access the inputted text. When the user switches tabs, I want background.js to grab what's in the textarea, even when form.html is not the active tab.

I have passed document.getElementById("textarea").value as a message to background.js with a button click but I want background.js to get this value when form.html is not the active tab (and eliminate the button eventually).

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style=''>
<head>
<head><title>activity</title></head>  
</head>
<body style="width:600px;">
<div id="myText"></div><p>
<button type="button" class="button" id="btn1">Input info</button>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```
function onWindowLoad(callback) {
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = url;
});

}
var button = document.getElementById("btn1");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    chrome.tabs.create({url:"/form.html"});
});

window.onload = onWindowLoad();
```

form.html

```
<style>
            html, body {
                }
            #myForm {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: auto;
                  position: relative;
                padding: 0;            }
        </style>
<body>
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form id="s3paths" class="form-container">
    <h2>Enter info here</h2><p>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="textarea" placeholder = "example of what to input">
</textarea></p>
<button type="button" class="button" id="btn2">Load</button>
<script src="form.js"></script>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
```

form.js

```
var button = document.getElementById("btn2");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert('loaded!');
    var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "paths"});
    var spaths = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    port.postMessage({paths: spaths});
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    alert(msg.paths);
  });
});
```

How can I get background.js to access document.getElementById("textarea").value of form.html from any tab the user switches to?

Comment: `form.html` needs to be open in a tab. Also I don't think background can directly access it, there needs to be some message passing.

Comment: The popup runs only when shown so when it's closed everything is immediately lost - you should send the text in a listener for `'input'` event in your form.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I found a work around. After I pass the value in the textarea as a message from form.js to background.js, I use chrome.storage.sync to store it so when I go to a different tab, it is still stored. (I kept the button click).

form.js

```
var button = document.getElementById("btn2");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert('loaded!');
    var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "paths"});
    var spaths = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    port.postMessage({paths: spaths});
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    var paths = msg.paths;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({key: paths}, function() {
    //alert('Value is set to ' + paths);
        });
  });
});
```

Elsewhere in background.js when I wish to use the stored value:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
        if (!result.key){alert('Value is empty')}
        else {alert(result.key);
        //did stuff with result.key
        };
        })
```

Comment: hey bro, could you assist with my issue? [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531443/chrome-storage-background-js-send-to-content-js-from-chrome-storage)